# iOS/AFNetworking TableView in TableView Controller does not display any data from array populated from response object

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am still newish to iOS Development and I have the following problem:

I am using AFNetworking to retrieve data from a RestFul WebService and while that works correctly and debugging showed that the data is successfully retrieved and stored in an array of Dictonaries (It's JSON Output) my table view does not update at all with the data.

My code is below, for my own method and viewDidLoad.

```
- (NSArray *) fetchLocations
{
// set up AFNetworking, connect and fetch the locations.
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.serviceURL]];
// set up object serializer and content types accepted as a response
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"client_uid": @"3232", @"session_key": self.sessionKey};

// initialize a new array then add objects to it.
NSMutableArray *locationsList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[manager POST:@"" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // Process Response Object
    NSDictionary *response = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
    // get the result, if it's null no point in going on just display an Alert View
    NSNumber *resultState = [responseObject objectForKey:@"result"];
    if ([resultState integerValue] == 0) {
        // something happened, display an error message
    }
    else if([resultState integerValue] == 1) {
        // we got an OK response, process the Dictionary data and return the array of objects.
        NSDictionary *locationsOutput = [response objectForKey:@"output"];

        for (NSString* key in locationsOutput) {
            [locationsList addObject:[locationsOutput objectForKey:key]];
            NSLog(@"Value is: %@", [locationsOutput objectForKey:key]);

        }
        NSLog(@"Locations added %i ", [locationsList count]);
    }

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // Handle Error
    UIAlertView *httpErrorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Request error" message:@"A service request error occurred. Please try again later" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [httpErrorView show];
}];
return locationsList;
}

// and viewDidLoad
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

   // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
   // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

  // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
  // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
  if([self.parentViewController  isKindOfClass:[BTMainViewController class]])
  {
      BTMainViewController *parent = (BTMainViewController *)self.parentViewController;
      self.sessionKey = parent.session;
      NSLog(@"URL is %@ ", self.sessionKey);
   }

  // also set the URL
  self.serviceURL = [apiURL stringByAppendingString:@"/myrestfulurlhere"];
  // fetch locations
  self.locations = [[self fetchLocations] mutableCopy];
  NSLog(@"Locations found %i ", [locations count]);
  //self.tableView.delegate = self;
  //self.tableView.dataSource = self;
  //[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I commended the setting of dataSource and delegate because in a previous project they were not needed at all and my UITableViewController seemed to work.

UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate methods are already conforming to protocol.

Thanks!

Comment: self.tableView.dataSource = self; self.tableView.delegate = self and make sure you have added <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> in your header file.

Comment: while sucessfully redrive data reload table [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: you have commented out last three lines in viewDidLoad.. why?

Comment: uncomment 2nd last and 3rd last lines

Comment: Oh i uncommented those, not much of a result. it still did not work. There is no data in the table. The protocol implementation is present in my header file as mentioned by JohnDoe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFNetworking's method you call is async which means, it returns before the actual result is returned. You have to uncomment

```
   self.tableView.delegate = self;
   self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

and call

`[self.tableView reloadData];`
 from the completion block of the network operation after this:
`NSLog(@"Locations added %i ", [locationsList count]);`

Comment: Thank you Rickye, it helped. I just had to turn the async method into a void rather than have it return an array which was always empty.